# Переход от строки ListView к строке в SynEdit

Tags: delphi, pascal

Помогите, пытаюсь сделать переход от строки ListView к строке в SynEdit, в программе найдена ошибка, которая показывает на какой строке SynEdit она находится, при нажатии на ошибку нужно сделать, чтобы переходило в строке в SynEdit ,указанной в ошибке
Вот то что получилось, но переход не работает

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1SelectItem(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  Selected: Boolean);
begin
   with TRegExpr.Create do
  try
    Expression := '\[line (\d+)\]'; // Ищем номер строки в сообщении об ошибке
    if Exec(Item.Caption) then
    begin
      TheLine := StrToInt(Match[1]); // запоминаем найденный номер строки с ошибкой
      SynEdit1.Invalidate; // и заставляем SynEdit перерисоваться. При этом изменится цвет строки
    end;
  finally`введите сюда код`
    Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Что за переменная/поле `TheLine` и как ее/его изменение должно повлиять на `SynEdit1`?

Comment: Вроде как в дальнейшем, она нужна, для отрисовки этой линии красным цветом

Comment: Наверное и тут никто не поможет(